# Featuretools create index from multiple columns

Tags: featuretools

I am trying to create an entity from a dataframe using the `entity_from_dataframe` function in featuretools. Is there a way to define the index if it comprises of more than one column. I'm unsure if I need a list, tuple or some other data structure. This is the code:

```
es=es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="credit",
                       dataframe=credit_df,
                       index=["ID1","ID2"]
                       )
```

It generates the following error regarding hashability

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single variable be your index. In your case, you should create a new column in your dataframe that is the concatenation of the two columns you want to use

```
df["index"] = df["ID1"].astype(str) + "_" + df["ID2"].astype(str)
```

Then, you can use `index` as the index when creating the entity.

Comment: Hi @MaxKanter , would this be fixed in the future versions of featuretools?